# How do I combine more than one face into one face?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

I'm trying to combine faces into one single face. It's basically like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> but it is faces instead of objects.

I already tried limited dissolve but it doesn't work.

Comment: a picture would nearly always help to show what you mean (even better two: one what it is, and one which show what you wanna have)

Answer (score 2):

In face selection mode select your faces > context menu > press 'D' or select 'Dissolve faces'. Try avoiding n-gons though.
[image: blender face dissolve join merge]

Comment: sorry, but that didnt work..

Comment: @Salam can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? what isn't working?

Comment: @fogings I think "dissolve edges" is found in the same menu, and is a better answer for the question.

Comment: @fogings Dissolve faces seem to do nothing. and uh. im trying to do what you just did in the gif. combining a few faces into one new face.